# Finding the average value

Tags: mean

I'm trying to create a data frame (df1) with n columns (3 in this case). Column 1 should be a random column from data frame df0. Column 2 should be the average of that same random column plus four other random column from df0. Column 3 should be the average of the earlier five plus another five random columns.

Comment: I think it is better to ask 3 questions because you have many text. also post an expected output.

Comment: Please add `set.seed` in order to make this reproducible.

Comment: Eitherway, when working with numeric columns it will be probably better to leave it as a matrix (for speed considerations). You could achieve you goal using `sapply(c(1, 5, 10), function(x) rowSums(df0[, random[1:x], drop = FALSE]))` for instance. You can adjust `c(1, 5, 10)` to whatever sequence you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to answer one by one your question. lets start with first

```
total <- 15 # Total number of columns in df0
sample <- 10 # Total number of columns I'm extracting from df0
values <- 4 # Number of rows 
random <- sample(total,sample,replace=FALSE)
df0 <- data.frame(matrix(data = rexp(values*total, rate = total), nrow = values, ncol = total))

#At first I select 10 random columns from df0 
df1 <- df0[, sample(ncol(df0), sample)]


#I would create an empty data frame 

df2 <- data.frame(matrix(, nrow =values , ncol = 3))


#then assign the first column of df1 to the output  , 
df2$X1 <- df1[,1] 

 #then you get the average of five first random selected to second column of df2 
df2$X2 <- rowMeans(subset(df1[1:5])) 

 #finally the average of 10 columns to the third column of df2 
df2$X3 <- rowMeans(subset(df1[1:10]))


> df2
#         X1         X2         X3
#1 0.18816542 0.12617238 0.08728368
#2 0.09855574 0.07592763 0.06069351
#3 0.12022571 0.06045562 0.07964574
#4 0.00260806 0.06172300 0.06225859
```

In order to remove all unwanted columns, I personally use something like below 
but I am sure there will be another way to do this

```
# for example you only want to keep column 3 and 5 then 
col_list = c("X3", "X5")
dfm = df0[,col_list]
```

Comment: Regarding the first question: It seems that at df1$X1, a random column is chosen, but that at df1$X2 the average of the first 5 columns of df1 is shown, rather than the average of the column shown in df1$X1 plus four other random columns. Is that indeed the case or am I reading this wrong? Just to be clear: the column with the average of 5 columns needs to included the first chosen column (in $X1) and the column with the average of 10 columns needs to include the first five, plus five other random columns.

Comment: @Joseph to be honest your question is a bit confusing. So, lets clear up your question. 1- you create a df0 , step 2, you want to select a random column from df0 and put it in df1. step 3, you want to take average of 5 first columns and put it in column 2 of df1, and finally you want to get the average of first 10 columns of df0 and put it in df1. Is it what you wanted ?

Comment: Let me put it differently. 1) I create df0. 2) I select 10 random columns from df0. 3) The first random column goes in df1$X1. 4) The average of the first 5 random columns goes in df1$X2 (these 5 of course include the first random column from step 3; so 4 new columns are included). 5) The average of all 10 random columns goes in df1$X3. Does this clarify things?

Comment: @Joseph I updated the answer, please check whether it gives you what you are looking for

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Would you also know a way to create df2 with different numbers of columns (so other than 3)? See question 2 of the original post. Of course I could simply add more columns so df2, but I'm trying to find a more efficient way to do this, for example with a loop. Nothing has worked so far, however.

Comment: @Joseph can you please again explain the problem. you meant the same df2 we created with 3 column we make it with more columns ? if so, what would be in that ? you want to add random columns to the df2 ?

Comment: I meant that I want to be able to change the number of selected columns (now 3; for 1, 5 and 10). I have found a way to do this, namely:

sample <- c(1,5,10)
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(,nrow=values,ncol=length(sample)))
for (i in 1:length(sample)) {
  df2[,i] <- rowMeans(subset(df1[1:sample[i]]))
}

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Joseph great ! and thanks for accepting my answer. I liked your answer too